# Is ~ symmeteric?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, wave-equation

I was given the following problem in my assignment:

> Define $a$~$b$ on the rationals by $a$~$b$ iff $b=ak^2$ for *some* rational number $k$.
>
> > Is **~** symmetric?.

Please somebody explain to me how to do this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Apply the definition of [Symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation).

Comment: Can you show that $b=ak^2$ implies $a=bk'^2$ ?

Comment: Note that $a\sim0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, but $0\not\sim a$ if $a\neq0$.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031899/is-the-following-transitive).

Answer (score 5):

To show that a relation $R$ **is** symmetric, you need to show that if $aRb$ then $bRa$. So suppose $a\sim b$. That means that there is some rational $k$ such that $b=ak^2$. You want to show that $b\sim a$, so: $$\mbox{Can you find a rational $l$ such that $a=bl^2$?}$$

---

To show that a relation $R$ **is not** symmetric, you need to find a counterexample: some $a, b$ such that $aRb$ but $b\not Ra$. Can you do this in this case? That is, can you find some $a, b$ such that

- there **is** a rational $k$ with $b=ak^2$, but
- there **is no** rational $l$ with $a=bl^2$?

---

Note that I haven't told you what the answer is - I've just described the strategy for *both* of the possible answers. You need to think about which strategy makes sense for this particular problem.

HINT: given $b=ak^2$, can you solve for $a$?

Comment: I let $k$ = $3/2$. So $b=ak^2$ $->$ $b=a(3/2)^2$ $->$ $b=9a/4$ $->$ $a=4b/9$. And $a=bk^2$ $->$ $a=b(3/2)^2$ $->$ $a=9b/4$. I concluded that ~ is not symmetric. Is that right?

Comment: @malcolm No, that's wrong: if $a\sim b$ via $k={3\over 2}$, then $b\sim a$ via $k={2\over 3}$. The $k$s don't have to be the same.

Comment: if we excluded 0 then symmetric and transitivity holds, however if we included 0 would make the relation not symmetric only transitive?--

Comment: @ELO Yes, that's right!