# Relations of a~b iff b = ak^2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Just need some verification for this question or another way to approach it.

Given: a~b is defined on the rationals by a~b iff $b = ak^2$ for $some$ rational number $k$.

Is it reflexive? Symmetric? Transitive?(Show the Equivalence relation)

Reflexive: Must show that a~a

$a=ak^2$

$1=k^2$ which checks out. Its Reflexive

Symmetric: Must show that a~b and b~a

a~b: $b=ak^2$, $\frac ba$=$k^2$

b~a: $a=bk^2$, $\frac ab$=$k^2$

Not symmetric.

Transitive:

a~b and b~c than we must show that a~c

a~b: $b=ak^2$,

b~c: $c=bk^2$

a~c: $c=ak^2$

This is were I am sorta stuck not sure if I am allowed to do the following:

since $c=ak^2$ and $c=bk^2$ I can find that a=b?not sure any help would be appreciated.

Noticing that if zero is excluded then we would have an equivalence relation. However, when zero is included would symmetric fail and both reflexive and transitive still hold?

Comment: Is it defined on *all* rationals, or only *nonzero* rationals?  Double-check to be sure, since your proof uses division, so you are dividing by zero in the former case.

Comment: I believe that when he defined rationals he defined it as non-zero.

Comment: That seems unlikely since $0$ is certainly rational. Double check the problem statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ~ symmeteric?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030648/is-symmeteric)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I would argue that other is duplicate of mine, I am showing it as an equivalence relation--I look for insight into the question I attempted not just asking for someone to help me solve it as in the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exclude $0$, then it is an equivalence relation.

Reflexive:
Yours is correct.

Symmetric:
$a\sim b\iff b=ak^2 \iff a=b(1/k)^2\iff b\sim a$.
Note that there just has to be *some* rational. $1/k$ is rational if $k$ is.

Transitive:
$a\sim b$ and $b\sim c \iff b=ak_1^2$ and $c=bk_2^2 \iff c=a(k_1k_2)^2 \iff a\sim c$.

Comment: While I wait for an email response from the professor, what would occur if include 0?

Comment: @EduardoO.  Examine the case(s) where your proof divides by 0.

Comment: @BillDubuque It will hold only for transitive and reflexive but not for symmetric

Comment: Shouldn't symmetric read as a∼b⟺b=$ak^2$⟺a=b$(\frac 1k)^2$ ⟺ b ~ a

Comment: Yeah I had them all backward. >.> shhhhh

Comment: @mrob other than the fact you placed it backward. Could you explain how it still holds for symmetric? Specifically, I guess what I am really asking is that your justification for stating $k^2$ and $(\frac 1k)^2$ are equivalent. I am guessing its just k does not need to be unique

Comment: @mrob I need a bit of clarity. For instance if I include zero as a rational. Than I would say reflexive and transitive still hold but symmetric fail?

Answer (score 3):

"some $k$" I interpret as; $k$ does not need to be unique.

$$
a \sim b \Leftrightarrow b = ak^2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{b}{k^2} = a \Leftrightarrow bp^2 = a \Leftrightarrow b \sim a
$$

if $k$ rational then $k = \frac{n}{m} \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \frac{n^2}{m^2} \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{m^2}{n^2}} \in \mathbb{Q} $

I Think with the above you can solve the last part, otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice since $a \cong b $ we can find $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $b = a q^2 $ and since $b \cong c$ we can find $\mathbf{another}$ $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $c = b p^2$. Choose $k^2 = p^2 q^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, then one has that

$$ c = a p^2q^2 = a k^2 $$

thus $a \cong c $

Comment: As for the symmetric and reflexive, does the work I show enough? Also thanks I always don't feel comfortable with added more to the problem.